# Javascript: forEach not working for Uint16Array (and Int16Array, Int16Array etc)

Tags: javascript, foreach

If I try to call forEach function for Uint16Array and and  get an error.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint16Array

For example

```js
var test = new  Uint16Array(2);
test[0]=1;
test[1]=2;
test.forEach( function(item, i, arr) { alert (item) });
```

Return:

> Uncaught TypeError: test.forEach is not a function

But code:

```js
var test = [1,2];
test.forEach( function(item, i, arr) { alert (item) });
```

Work fine.

And

```js
var test= new Array();
test[0]=1;
test[1]=2;
test.forEach( function(item, i, arr) { alert (item) });
```

Work fine too.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The typed arrays don't inherit from `Array.prototype`

Comment: it looks like that is coming: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.forEach()`, but it's not on the typed array prototypes (*edit* — at least not yet, and/or not universally). Thus you have to find it from a regular array and use `.call()`:

```
[].forEach.call(someTypedArray, function(value, index) {
  // your code here
});
```

Some prefer to explicit reference `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(someTypedArray, function(value, index) {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: Why do some prefer that?

Comment: @thomas well I don't have much of an opinion one way or the other, so I'm not sure. I think it's one of those (mostly) pointless debates, but perhaps some fervent partisan will add an explanatory (or inflammatory) comment :)

Comment: Thank you so much.   I nearly went crazy trying to understand why does not work.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MDN `TypedArray.prototype.forEach()` documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/forEach).

It is not available yet - in the browser compatability section it states it is available in Firefox 38 which is due to be released on 2015-05-19.

Comment: Now I will take a closer look to  "Browser compatibility" section .